# Insert Image from Image control to excel as Icon with Link using VBA

Tags: vba

I am a beginner in Excel VBA.I have Image control in vba form. An image is displayed selecting from folder. What I want is to insert and save the same image to Cell D.Here is code

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click()
    Dim irow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim PictDir As String, PictType As String
    Dim SNo As Long
    Dim Image As Object
    Set ws = Worksheets("SafetyReport")
    SNo = ws.Range("A1", ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    If SNo = 1048576 Then
       SNo = 1
    End If


    irow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

    With ws
     .Range("D" & irow) = Me.Image.Picture
End Sub

Private Sub Image_Click()
    Dim PictFileName As String
    Dim PicPath As String
    PictFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename
    PicPath = PictFileName

    If Len(Dir(PicPath)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox PicPath & " does not exist."
    Else
        Me.Image.Picture = LoadPicture(PicPath)
        Me.Repaint
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming "Image1" is the name of the `Image` control in your UserForm, and concentrating on the specific task you need to accomplish, then you may want to consider the following code

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub btnSave_Click()
    Dim myCell As Range

    With Worksheets("SafetyReport")
        Set myCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        If Me.Tag <> "" Then ' if any path has been stored in userform 'Tag' property
            With .Pictures.Insert(Me.Tag)
                With .ShapeRange
                    .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                    .Width = myCell.Width
                    .Height = myCell.Height
                End With
                .Left = myCell.Left
                .Top = myCell.Top
                .Placement = 1
            End With
            Me.Tag = "" ' clear 'Tag' property for subsequent uses
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Image1_Click()
    Dim PicPath As Variant

    PicPath = Application.GetOpenFilename
    If PicPath = False Then
        MsgBox "No files selected"
    Else
        Me.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(PicPath)
        Me.Repaint
        Me.Tag = PicPath ' store the picture path in Userform 'Tag' property
    End If
End Sub
```